# How do I get DotNetOpenAuth to return correct claimed identifiers?

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I'm implementing and OpenId Provider based on the DotNetOpenAuth OpenIdProviderMVC sample. From the RP, I'm creating an OpenIdRelyingParty, and calling CreateRequest with

```
http://localhost:PORT/User/xrds
```

This correctly redirects to the OP, and everything seems to work, but the ClaimedIdentifier that comes back is *always*

```
http://localhost:PORT/User/xrds
```

even when I'm expecting

```
http://localhost:PORT/user/username
```

where username is the user I logged in with. Is this an issue with the sample, am I using an incorrect URL as the UserSuppliedIdentifier, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a different URL as UserSuppliedIdentifier. For instance, use something like `http://localhost:PORT/Discovery` that executes an action returning the XRDS file. And for identity discovery, define a route to redirect `http://localhost:PORT/user/username` to a action Identity serving the XRDS file for identity verification.

That worked for me.

Good luck.